# List of `N` largest values (positive or negative) in Excel, conditional on text fields

Tags: excel-formula

I'll simplify the sheet to the following:

Column A: Has a list of numbers that are either positive or negative

Column B: Has a list of corresponding 'names' (they are text strings)

Column C: Has either a yes/no type response

Column D: Are also text responses with 4 or so different types.

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

A separate column (say E:E) that picks the top 10 (either negative or positive) numbers from A, but prints the adjacent text 'names' from B in the cells in E.

In addition to this, it only prints these names IF there is a certain word in the corresponding cell in C AND a certain word in the corresponding cell D. I assume this latter condition will be an IF(OR()) out the front, but would like some advice for this. I've seen from reading online people find the largest, or smallest +/- number...but not a list of the top 10 (either pos/neg).

Any advice appreciated

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If a positive and negative number have the same absolute value i.e. -9 and 9 which comes first? Say you have a list of eight -9's and four 9's how would you decide the top 10?

Comment: @Andreas This is because neither the MAX(), MIN(), LARGE(), SMALL() functions achieve what I need (or at least with my understanding of them), so I didn't include them because I don't think that will be useful. Put simply, for the important part of this formula, I don't know where to start so I have no meaningful attempt.

Comment: @shash678 I've re-read your question. I can probably work something else out if its just the absolute values. So consider that for this case, it doesn't matter about the order. Specifically, it doesnt matter if 9 is at #1 and -9 is at #2, vice versa

Comment: If your open to creating a new column manually, you could create one with the absolute values of A, sort it in descending order, select the top 10 etc... If you want to do it in code It will probably be something similar at the minimum involving sorting by absolute value in some fashion.

Comment: @shash678 It needs to be formulaic (as opposed to using 'sort' descending) because the long/short exposure is calculated daily...so I can just shift+F9 the sheet and it shows me the top 10.

Comment: Can you add some sample data? Or at least clarify a point for me... is the condition of certain words in C and D taken into account when finding the top 10? For example, if 23456 is the highest absolute value, but doesn't have the words in C and D, is it in the top 10 or not?

Comment: @BigBen I can't add the actual data as it's private info, though I could change it up if the following doesn't help enough. Yes, the condition is taken into account. For example, if C and D don't have the required words it's not included. To maybe make things easier, consider that I need the cell in C to be ="Bonds" and the cell in D to be ="Bank". So if those conditions are not met...the 'name' in from B is not considered in the top 10. If that helps.

Comment: Yes that helps a lot, thanks.

Comment: One more question - do you ever have a zero in column A, or are there only non-zero numbers?

Comment: @BigBen yes there can be zeros

Answer (score 0):

I have a "Top 10 movers" solution that will work most* of the time.

Data in rows 2:50
  Symbol in column B
  Values to test in column C

Helper columns:
    =Large(c$2:C$50, 1) in E2, Large(c$2:C$50, 2) in E3, etc
    TOP 10 positives

```
=-Small(c$2:C$50, 1) in F2, -Small(c$2:C$50, 2) in F3, etc
TOP 10 negatives (as positive values)

=large(e2:f10, 1) in G2, large(e2:f10, 1) in G3, etc
Abs(Top 10)

=IF(ISNA(MATCH(G2, C$2:c$50, 0)), "S", "L") in H3, etc
Test for Large or Small*

=IF(H3 = "L", 1, -1) * G3, etc in I3
Restores + / -

=INDEX($B$2:$B$50, MATCH(I3, OFFSET($B$2:$B$50, 0, 1), 0), 1) in J3
Returns symbol
```

- Problem: If abs(neg) = pos value, the Test in column H will always return symbol corresponding to positive value. A slight improvement might be to see if value already exists in the list, but if there's e.g., +9, -9, -9, we have the same issue.

Hope this helps. If you figure out a 100% solution, please let me know